# Solving for an equation for one variable (algebra)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I have to solve for $n$ in this equation $M=a+c(n-6)$. I have already used the distributive property.  However, I don’t have any like terms. I have tried different ways to get the answer, but none of them seem to logically make sense. How would you solve this? Again, I’m solving for $n$.

Comment: Step one: Open the parentheses. What's the result you get after that?

Comment: I got M=a+cn-6c.

Comment: good.  now can you get all the terms not involving $n$ on one side of the equation?

Comment: Here is my work: I subtracted a from m, I also subtracted c from cn, then I added c, to -6c.

Comment: Subtract $a-6c$ from both sides of the equation

Comment: I am little confused, how would that be formatted? @J.W.Tanner

Comment: $M=a+cn-6c\implies M-(a-6c)=a+cn-6c-(a-6c)\implies M-a+6c=cn$; that accomplishes the goal of getting all the terms not involving $n$ on one side of the equation

Comment: Thank you. If you don't mind, can you explain this part? M-(a-6c)=a+cn-6c-(a-6c). How did you get rid of the second part of the equation? I distributed the first half, and got a logical answer. But I am stuck on how to get rid of the second half. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: I subtracted $a-6c$ from both sides of the equation.  The right side has $(a-6c)-(a-6c)=0$

Answer (score 1):

It is $$M-a=cn-6c$$
$$M-a+6c=cn$$so $$n=\frac{M-a+6c}{c}$$ for $$c\neq 0$$

Comment: Did you mean $M\color{red}-a$ where you wrote $Ma$ in the numerator?

Comment: No, I meant this part a+cn-6c-(a-6c). I am lost at this part. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: @gnatgnat2019:  I think your comment immediately above was not intended as a response to my comment immediately above that, and it should therefore be deleted

Comment: My apologies sir. I did mean to respond to you. I'm so sorry if I did something wrong. I'm new to this website. Thank you for your help. @J.W.Tanner

Comment: Again, my apologies. @J.W.Tanner

Answer (score 1):

You used the distributive property to get from $M=a+c(n-6)$ to $M=a+cn-6c.$

Since your goal is to solve for $n$,

subtract $a-6c$ from each side to get  all the terms not involving $n$ on one side of the equation:

$M-(a-6c)=a+cn-6c-(a-6c)\implies M-a+6c=cn$.

Now simply divide both sides by $c$ to solve for $n$.

(You can do so provided $c\ne0$.  If $c=0, $ you could not solve for $n$; $n$ could be anything.)

Comment: Thank you for explaining. So when you subtract a-6c from each side M-(a-6c)=a+cn-6c-(a-6c), how did you get rid of the second half of the equation? I am talking about this part a+cn-6c(a-6c). I am so sorry for bothering. @J.W. Tanner

Comment: $a+cn−6c−(a−6c)=cn+a−6c−(a−6c)=cn+0=cn$

Comment: Wow! that made so much sense now. Thank you again. Really appreciate it @J.W. Tanner